# django remote access basics

Tags: python, django, remote-access

i have scripts producing outputs and other scripts reading these. All data should be read/written from/to a database on a server with corresponding information from multiple **remote** terminals.

I felt like django seems to be a nice solution.
Unfortunately the documentation and examples are only about setting up the data base and accessing it locally or via a browser. I get the impression that django is not offering this since i can not find anything about it and i was searching a lot.

Could someone help or link some examples how to write/read to the database on a server from an other machine?

Cheers,
Daniel

Comment: 1. Add a proxy endpoint that will take data from every client and write it into the database. 2. Add permissions to share database connection credentials and connect with that credential directly.

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. Any hints where i could find examples or tutorials?

Comment: [Django docs](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/)

Comment: Thanks - i have worked through them already. As far as i have seen, there is nothing on remote acces via a web service or so. Do you know anything more specific related to the problem?

Comment: Django doesn't care where the database is; just configure the db settings to point to the address where it lives. What, exactly, is your question?

Comment: I have multiple questios related to this. That's why i asked for tutorials.  One more specific question could be: How do i write to a database that is on an other server. An example would be really helpfull since i am new to the db programming.

Comment: Just provide settings with URL to RDBM server and connection credentials. Maybe, you have to read something about SQL first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the end, I figured out with the help of [this](https://www.caktusgroup.com/blog/2011/10/24/django-without-web/)!